# Choosing a sampler

Tags: audiokit

over the past week or so I’ve been trying to find a workflow for original sample generation to eventually  be used in an audiokit app, obviously at some point Im going to have to decide which of AudioKits sampler classes best fits my needs and I have a few
Questions about what I have found so far :

I won’t be getting Logic Pro anytime soon so I think EXS24 is not an option right now, as a side question -  are there any other
Apps which can generate .esx24 files?
The MIDISampler in AudioKit has a method .loadSoundFont( - is there a documented example of this?  (couldn’t find any in cookbook)
I was able to get this working with .sf2 files but I want to make sure Im doing it properly.
There is a Sampler class in DunneAudioKit - I was also able to establish a workflow in this using .sfz files - this seems pretty good
Currently I am deliberating between the MIDISampler in AudioKit and the Sampler in DunneAudioKit
Are there any other options in the audiokit framework(s) that I should consider? Also the file formats .sf2 and .sfz I am guessing are probably going to stay in use for some time - has anybody heard about either of those two being deprecated or changed in a major way?

Answer (score 2):

GarageBand can make AUPreset files and MainStage can make EXS24 files suitable for AppleSampler. I've not tried the DunneSampler but I believe that is the one AudioKit Pro uses for several of their commercial apps. There isn't an example in the Cookbook for SF2 in AppleSampler but it should be very similar. SF2 has been around for a very long time and I imagine SFZ will be too.

Comment: Nick, these garageband presets, are you referring to .patch files? I tried loading those but to no avail

Comment: They are .aupreset files that you make in the AUSampler. https://youtu.be/tdHWcAX-flQ 
AUPreset files can be a bit limited but you should be able to get a basic instrument loaded.

Comment: Just watched the vid you sent there and read some of the discussions and tutorials linked in it, - I might end up going with the .sfz option .... don't know yet, there are a few more factors to consider than I first thought ....